# Проблема с типом TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql, oracle

Здравствуйте. Есть параметризованный запрос, в котором есть условие на сравнение дат. Выглядит так:

```
where mydate > :start_date and mydate < :end_date
```

Тип mydate, TIMESTAMP(6). Вот как я подаю параметр:

> 31.01.2018 19:00:00

.
Вылетает ошибка:

> ORA-01830: шаблон формата даты завершается перед преобразованием всей строки ввода
>   01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Пример данных в этом поле из таблицы:

> 04.12.13 08:55:17,445000000

Что я делаю не так? Как это можно побороть?

Comment: `:start_date` и `:end_date` откуда приходят? Скорее всего, происходит неявное преобразование типов, в настройках сессии установлен какой-то формат по умолчанию, который не совпадает с приходящим.

Comment: @Dmitry из c# всё выполняется нормально, а вот когда выполняю в sql developer и сам подставляю дату в качестве параметра, тогда уже и вылетает ошибка

Answer (score 2):

> Пример данных в этом поле из таблицы:
>
> 04.12.13 08:55:17,445000000

Это не пример данных, это пример *отображения* данных. Данные в поле с типом `TIMESTAMP` хранятся в своем особом формате, а в строку преобразуются только при выводе. Когда вы видите `04.12.13 08:55:17,445000000`, это значит, что просто формат по умолчанию такой (скорее всего что-то вроде `dd.mm.yy hh:mi:ss.fffffffff`). Соответственно, С# сам преобразует данные к нужному формату, а вы просто даете на вход строку, не соответствующую тому, что ожидает СУБД. Вариантов выхода три:

- писать преобразование типов в явном виде (и подавать на вход строку, соответствующую формату):

  ```
  where mydate > to_timestamp(:start_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
    and mydate < to_timestamp(:end_date,   'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  ```
- изменить настройки сессии в SQL Developer:

  ```
      alter session set NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'
  ```
- писать в SQL DEveloper текст в ожидаемом формате - что-то вроде `31.12.18 19:00:00,000000000` в вашем случае

Вообще обычно рекомендуется использовать первый способ, но если вам надо часто копипастить один и тот же запрос в C# и обратно (в C# `to_timestamp` будет лишним), то второй способ будет удобнее.

Документация в помощь: [to_timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions229.htm#SQLRF06142), [Datetime Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions229.htm#SQLRF06142).

P. S. А что вы не пишете `mydate between :start_date and :end_date`? Удобнее же.